# How to use Gmail's "Send mail as" feature when SMTP server requires 2 factor authentication

Tags: gmail, email, multi-factor-auth

I used to use the "send mail as" feature so I could use the gmail interface for my work emails instead of outlook.  My workplace has now mandated 2-factor authentication for their single-sign on, so when I go to add my password in the SMTP configuration, I get an Authentication Failed error because I don't have the opportunity to add the second factor.  Is there a way to get around this?

[image]

Comment: Any updates on this topic?

Comment: unfortunately not. I haven't done much further investigation since posting this. A colleague did some digging more recently but wasn't able to find anything either.

Comment: Same results from my side - thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit old, but I believe the answer is you need to create an App Password for the account you want to use as an alias. E.g. you have two email accounts a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com. b@gmail.com has two-factor authentication. You want to be able to send emails from a@gmail.com as b@gmail.com. Set up an App Password for b@gmail.com using [these instructions](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9437157?hl=en#:%7E:text=On%20your%20computer%2C%20go%20to,step%20verification%20for%20your%20account.). Then when you're asked for a password for b@gmail.com in the "Send mail as" dialog box, use this app password.

Comment: worked for me..